# Item Selection handler not working on Iphone 6 - iOS 11 ( pod SearchTextField )

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to make a Autocomplete TextField with drop down.In android there is very handy and beautiful Autocomplete widget. But Sadly I did not found any here iOS.

So I tried [this](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField) library. It is so easy to use and it looks good with UI. But there is a problem, and that Is when I search any Item and that got list in dropdown, I am unable to select any of them.The code goes like this:

```
myTextField.itemSelectionHandler = { filteredResults, itemPosition in
        // Just in case you need the item position
        let item = filteredResults[itemPosition]
        print("Item at position \(itemPosition): \(item.title)")

        // Do whatever you want with the picked item
        self.myTextField.text = item.title
    }
```

I am working on project and just included it. But it is really not getting called. Do you experienced same issue? and how to fix it ?

Comment: Could you provide some more information on how you implemented the library? Did you use cocoapods to add it to your project? How did you add it to your page? Did you take a look at the example project and copy the implementation?

Comment: Yes I add it using CocoaPods. Also  I implemented same as shown in demo.

Answer (score 0):

Two common things to forget if you are not an experienced iOS dev are:

1. Connecting the input to your viewcontroller via an outlet (https://youtu.be/G_JKLxPYd60?t=208)
2. Specifying the custom class of the input in the storyboard

I added 2 screenshots to show you what I mean.

[image: Adding referencing outlet and specifiying custom class]

[image: Adding referencing outlet pt 2]

I have created a [small example project](https://github.com/Farmertjes/SearchTextFieldMinimalExample) to hopefully help you out.

Comment: I done this I know. Though I am new in IOS but I have done this

Comment: Could you make a minimal example project on Github for people to look at? Add the link to your original question.

Comment: I am using from gitHub, do you need its link?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a small example project. Hope it helps!

Comment: project fails to load

Comment: Please run "pod install" in the project root and then open the workspace project (not the normal project)

Comment: let me try again

Comment: its open up the project, but no files are being shown when I installed pod

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179381/discussion-between-farmertjes-and-android-teem).